# Ambiguous type name error

Tags: ios, swift, swiftyuserdefaults

I'm trying to re-compile SwiftyUserDefaults(https://github.com/radex/SwiftyUserDefaults) to add Carthage support, but on attempt to compile I see following error:

> Ambiguous type name 'Proxy' in 'NSUserDefaults'

for following code

```
public func ?= (proxy: NSUserDefaults.Proxy, @autoclosure expr: () -> Any) {
    if !proxy.defaults.hasKey(proxy.key) {
        proxy.defaults[proxy.key] = expr()
    }
}
```

and

> 'Proxy' is ambiguous for type lookup in this context

for

```
public subscript(key: String) -> Proxy {
    return Proxy(self, key)
}
```

As I understand - problem is with class Proxy, that's embedded in extension.

```
public extension NSUserDefaults {
    class Proxy {
        private let defaults: NSUserDefaults
        private let key: String

        private init(_ defaults: NSUserDefaults, _ key: String) {
            self.defaults = defaults
            self.key = key
        }

        // MARK: Getters

        public var object: NSObject? {
            return defaults.objectForKey(key) as? NSObject
        }

        // ..................................       

    }
}
```

I've looked for documentation, but there isn't any reference that a class can be used in extension.

Is it right?

Comment: Project is compiling just fine after cloning on my machine. Which version of Xcode are you using ?

Comment: Version 6.3.2 (6D2105)

Comment: Hmm using 6.3.1 (6D1002) at the moment. Maybe something changed in the new version and SwiftyUserDefaults did not yet update.

Comment: i've added .xcodeproj for main library (currently there are only .xcodeproj for tests, but not for entire lib) - with template "Cocoa touch framework"

Comment: http://take.ms/PFIxD nothing changed in main file, but there are error :(

Comment: i've archived modified version - https://www.dropbox.com/s/zm7q6nr8vm6a04v/SwiftyUserDefaults.zip?dl=0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are compiling the `SwiftlyUserDefaults.swift` file twice in your target SwiftlyUserDefaultsTests: once in the `SwiftlyUserDefaults.framework` (which is a dependency of SwiftlyUserDefaultsTests), and once in the "Compile Source" build phase.

Just remove the `SwiftlyUserDefaults.swift` file from the "Compile Source" build phase of your SwiftlyUserDefaultsTests target and you should be good to go.

[image]

Comment: I have the same problem, and I can not resolve it. Can you please help me?

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38500798/how-to-include-the-library-in-the-target-for-ui-test-class-in-xcode